# Python redis.client Lock not working

Tags: python, redis

I have two processes that attempt to acquire a lease via `redis.lock(...).acquire()`. I would expect one to fail and one to work. However, there are instances where BOTH claim to have successfully acquired the lock.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in versions prior to 2.8.0 (fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/commit/5353389f469beb43e2c60d75e347002da5572321)), where `int(time.time())` was used with `setnx`. This allowed multiple processes to call lock  in the same second and believe that they won.

See the change log [here](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/CHANGES).